# Get query of exp:channel

Tags: channel, query

Can I get the sql query after calling exp:channel.
I want to see the query behind an exp:channel call?
Is this possible by any debugging process?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you turn on the [Output Profiler](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#display-output-profiler), you will be able to see the list of SQL queries generated for any page.